# How to add paging in CMSRepeater from code side in kentico

Tags: kentico

I want to add a paging control on my custom web-part so I can customize the paging style. I am using a CMSRepeater for binding the data. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using CMSRepeater you can try to add UniPager to it. This control is easy customizable. Please see this link: https://docs.kentico.com/k9/references/kentico-controls/generic-controls/paging-controls/unipager

Comment: Its useful Thanks . But could you confirm it will work for nested repeater?. I have used nested repeater in my custom web part.and unipager is not working on this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a custom webpart to setup different styling for paging.  Simply add a repeater to a page template and add the Universal Pager webpart to the page.  In the Universal Pager webpart set the Web part control ID in the target control name from the repeater you want to hook it up to.  Then in the Universal Pager webpart define your transformations.  Again, no need for a custom webpart for this, just use 2 already created webparts together.

Comment: Thanks. I have used custom web-part for done some custom functionality. now my paging issue has resolved.  I have used PagerControl property of repeater &  managed paging layout by some css.